# getting error java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, view

I am new at Android. I am getting  errors `java.lang.NullPointerException` and `java.lang.RuntimeException` application force closes.

```
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.md.ExpertRemote/com.md.ExpertRemote.first.ExpertRemote}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1969)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1845)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.md.ExpertRemote.first.ExpertRemote.onCreate(ExpertRemote.java:286)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-18 06:04:12.676: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong in ExpertRemote.java:286. Hard to tell more without code...

Comment: The problem is in line 286: `com.md.ExpertRemote.first.ExpertRemote.onCreate(ExpertRemote.java:286)`. Please post the code.

Comment: Hurry up, because the downvoting has commenced... and please try to look at the line yourself if you see a variable that could create a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Not the whole code : the relevant one. After you checked the line to see if you find it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the stack trace, it looks like this line:

```
at com.md.ExpertRemote.first.ExpertRemote.onCreate(ExpertRemote.java:286)
```

... is probably calling `ViewGroup.addView()` and passing a `null` value as one of the arguments. That argument is only being validated a few levels down, hence the extra lines of the stack trace.

Look at line 286 in ExpertRemote.java, and work out why one of the values could be null. (In my experience of questions like this, it's often because you're using the wrong kind of ID to find an object.) Unfortunately we can't give more specific help than that without seeing the code.

It's important to use this as a learning experience in three respects:

- Learn how to read stack traces. One very simple first pass is to find the first place where *your* code is mentioned.
- Learn how to use the debugger. While I haven't done any Android development myself, I'd *expect* that when running in the debugger, the exception would trigger execution to pause at the problematic place. Even if it doesn't, using a debugger will help you to validate any diagnosis of the problem (e.g. checking that the argument value really is null)
- Learn how to [post better questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709094611/http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx): think about what you'd need to know if *you* were trying to solve the problem. Of course, doing this should also help you to solve your own problems in the first place...

Comment: thanks can i delete my question?

Comment: @madhumita: Not now it's been answered with upvotes, no... after it's closed, others may suggest deletion though.